# Requirejs main.js could not be found

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I started learning JS and at the moment I am working on Require.js.
Here is the deal, I have simple html page and js in it:

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src= "js/lib/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I do really have **main.js in the** root/**js folder** but by some reason page is looking for main.js in the root. Error:

```
*Failed to load resource file:///work/programs/brackets/4proj/main.js*
```

If I put main.js in the root (data-main="main") all will work as expected but I don't want to have a lot of *js in the root, even 2 js files. I saw in the require.js examples that it is possible but I have had no success with it.

What I've tried:

```
/js/main.js
./js/main.js
//js/main.js
```

**and all the same without extension.** It's still not working.

Here is project structure.
Project folder - 4prog/

- /js
- /js/lib/ <- jquery.js,require.js
- /css
- index.html

**p.s. I am using Ubuntu + brackets + chromium.**

Comment: Could you describe your directory structure more clearly? Also, have you tried removing `.js` from `data-main`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to remove .js. It did not help.
The problem is that page wants to load main.js from the 4prog (root directory). And I want to make it load main.js from the /js/main.js

Comment: Using `file:` URIs causes a huge pile of gotchas when dealing with dynamically loading anything. It really isn't worth doing development in an environment without a webserver.

Comment: Do you mean I should try to use some server like apache?
But, example I've seen in the require.js api is next
 <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
they have not mentioned anything about webservers.
And it should work in that way.
If there is any another way to deal with it I'll do it on server.

Comment: Yes, use something like Apache. Most JS documentation doesn't mention when a server is required because it is assumed that anything doing web development will be using a server (because not using one causes all sorts of problems as mentioned previously).

Comment: For full-fledged web development running a server of some sort becomes a necessity. However, I've run dozens of mini RequireJS demos composed of multiple files, all served from ``file:`` to test ideas (and to answer SO questions): none of them required a server to run properly.

Comment: I assume it could be a problem with access or smth like that. 
@Louis do you have any idea? If it could be solved without server - it would be awesome

Comment: @Noob.Net What I'm seeing in the question seems okay to me. If you pass a configuration to RequireJS, it would be good to see it.

Comment: No, Guys, I did the same with python simpleHTTPServer and main.js was not found.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

.js does have meaning to require - it makes it behave like an absolute path.

So does prefixing with "/".

You didn't explicitly mention trying

```
<script data-main="js/main" src= "js/lib/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which is what works on my system (from file: !), so I can only assume that either you've got something else going on, or you didn't try that.

You didn't mention your version of require, your OS, or your browser, so that could be it, but it's more likely that trying to do an absolute path with require is messing you up without serving from a web server.

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful.
I do know it could be anything, cuz of my ubuntu, brackets + chromium.
Thanks @Jim. I will try to use web server.